# Adding elements into ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist

```
class solution{
    public List<List<Integer>> solve(int[] nums) 
    {
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){
            if(hm.containsKey(nums[i])){
                hm.put(nums[i], hm.get(nums[i])+1);
            }
            else{
                hm.put(nums[i], 1);
            }
            if(ans.size()<hm.get(nums[i])){
                ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
            int row = hm.get(nums[i]) - 1;
            int el = nums[i];
            ans.add(row, el); //Line 18: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to List<Integer>
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

When trying to add elements into ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>, I am getting

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to List<Integer>

I have used the syntax obj.add(row, element);

How can we add elements at a specific row in ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Comment: You're trying to add an individually Integer to `ans`, but you should add it to one of the lists **in** `ans`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions using correctly this site. Be sure to also explain what solve() is trying to do, share example inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs..

Comment: If the source of this problem has a web page, it might help to add a link to that page.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<List<Foo>>` is regarded as a 2-dimensional (2D)`List`. Let's say you have

`List<List<Foo>> myList = = new ArrayList<> ();`

Later in the code, assuming the elements are, in fact present, to access a specific `Foo`, two subscripts are used:

```
Foo myFoo = myList.get(12).get(7);
```

That is equivalent to this:

```
List<Foo> row = myList.get(12); // returns a `List<Foo>`
Foo myFoo = row.get(7);
```

If the elements exist, and you want to add one at a specific location, you could also use two subscripts:

```
myList.get(15).add (20,newFoo (482));
```

If `myList.get(15)`, doesn't exist, you might create it:

```
List<Foo> line = new List<> ();
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
   line.add (new Foo (i));
}
myList.add (15, line);
```

A general way to create and fill a 2D `List` is to create one row at a time, adding each row as it is completed:

```
List<List<Foo>> myList = new <> ArrayList<> ();
int outerSize,  innerSize;
...
for (int outer = 0; outer < outerSize; outer++) {
   List<Foo> line = new ArrayList<> ();
   innersize = getInner (outer);
   for (int inner = 0; i < innerSize; inner++) {
       line.add (new Foo (outer, inner);
   }
   myList.add (line);
}
```

**NOTES**

- In your code, since you are using `<Integer>` for the inner type, you can rely on the compiler using auto-boxing and unboxing.
- When adding an element to a `List` with an index, the value of the index must be greater than or equal to zero, and less than or equal to the current `size()` of the `List`. The `add (int index, E e)` method will *not* fill with nulls if the value of the index is greater than `size ()`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @Old Dog Programmer

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line from:

```
ans.add(row, el);
```

to:

```
ans.get(row).add(el)
```

has worked.

For `List<List<Integer>>` first accessing the row required using `Obj.get(row)`(outer List) and then adding the element(inner List) has worked.